# I'm having issues with assigning IDs properly in CSS

Tags: html, css

So, I'm having this issue with trying to make code apply to items within a sublist, which I have named "Horizontal"

```
<nav class="horizontal" id="horizontal">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
```

This should in turn translate over to my CSS file as so

```
#horizontal > li {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    display: inline-block;
    horizontal-align: left;
```

I know the file is linked to my HTML doc as it has worked with other style rules.. I'd like to know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, side note: for this snippet

```
display: inline-block;
horizontal-align: left;
}
```

The effect I'm trying to go for here is to display the item as a block and float it to the left, I'd like to know if I'm on the right track with that code.

Finally, I seem to be having an issue with the font-color and/or text-color properties, as neither seem to work for my lists as such:

```
#horizontal > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255,101,101);
    text-color: black;
```

The background color changes, but the text remains the same.

Comment: Change `#horizontal > li` to `#horizontal > ul > li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`#horizontal > li`**

Where **`> li`** look for and LI element with a Parent element that has an ID `horizontal`

The **>** *(greater than)* operator looks for a  direct descendant of a parent element. In your example, `#horizontal` is the parent element and the direct descendant is the UL.

Therefore, the effect you expect on the LI would not be applied.

You can use

`#horizontal li`, or `#horizontal ul li`, or `#horizontal > ul > li` which has a higher specificity weight.